# Saving the content of a QLineEdit object into a string variable (C++)

Tags: c++, qt5, c++14

I've looked around the Qt Documentation, but within my project, I'd like to having most of the non-graphical 'more thinking' part of my program be on a seperate .cpp file.
Given that, I was wanting to take the text typed into a QLineEdit object and save it as a string after the user triggers the 'returnPressed' action, but when I type:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed()

{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("The entry has been modified.");
    msgBox.exec();
    //The line which should save the contents of the QLineEdit box:
    string input = QLineEdit::text();
}
```

...Into the template provided by the Qt Creator IDE (with all necessary slots hopefully created) The compiler returns

```
In member function 'void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed()'
cannot call member function 'QString...'
```

... and so on.

How should I rewrite my code to do this correctly?

Answer (score 3):

1. You must choose how to store the string. Your main options are: array of `char`s, std::string from the standard library, and QString from Qt. If you need to use the string in a third party library then you might need to store it in an std::string or an array of `char`s, but if that's not the case then I suggest that you simply use QString as it is widely used throughout Qt, although you can convert a QString to std::string or array of `char`s.
2. You must actually retrieve the text. To do this you must call the text() function on the QLineEdit instance, not on the QLineEdit class itself. All widgets can be accessed through the `ui` pointer. Open the designer and check the name of the line edit, the default name is `lineEdit`, so try replacing the line

`string input = QLineEdit::text();`

with the line

`QString input = ui->lineEdit->text();`

Comment: Your method works well, but how should I type cast the QString into an std::string?

Comment: A slight change: std::string input = ui->lineEdit->text().toStdString();

Comment: I typed Dolby's idea in, but now creator is giving me a 'conversion from ' QString' to non-standard type 'std::string' requested' error. What could be wrong now?

Comment: I don't know why but I had to use `ui.lineEdit` instead of `ui->`.

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
lineEdit->text().toStdString()
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate a bit about why this is correct and why the asker's code was not working.

Answer (score 0):

For Qt6 this is the best solution that I found

`string input = ui->lineEdit->text().toStdString();`

A more developed answer from 'alagner'

Comment: I think an edit of alagner's answer would be a better choice. Even then, this contributes almost nothing on top of their answer.

Comment: Queue is full cannot edit :)